# (new Array(10)).map(function() { return 1;}) returns [, , , , , ...] ... Why?

Tags: javascript

I would expect the following code to return `[1,1,1,1...]`

```
(new Array(10)).map(function() { return 1;})
```

but it returns `[, , , , , ...]`.

Moreover,
`(new Array(10)).length == 10` and `(new Array(10))[0] == undefined` are true.

And for `z = function(){return 0;};` the expression `z(undefined) === 0` is also true.

Yet I have noticed that `[,,,,,,,,,,].map(function() { return 1; })` also returns `[,,,,....]`.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 7):

> So. I would expect the following code to return [1,1,1,1...].
>
> `(new Array(10)).map(function() { return 1;})`
>   But it returns [, , , , , ...].

Right, because `new Array(10)` creates an array with **no elements** with a `length` of 10, and [`map`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) only iterates over elements that actually exist. (And yes, this **is** surprising. :-) )

> Moreover, `(new Array(10)).length == 10` and `(new Array(10))[0] == undefined` are `true`.

Again correct, because (again) `new Array(10)` doesn't put any elements in the array, so accessing `[0]` gives you `undefined`.

JavaScript's standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), and they can have a `length` that's a positive number without having any entries in them. They're a form of "sparse" array.

Let's take a simpler example:

```
var a = new Array(10);
a[2] = 1;
```

That array contains **one** element, the element at index `2`. There is no element at index `0`, no element at index `1`, and no elements at indexes `3` and above. It just has gaps there. You can tell by asking it:

```
console.log(0 in a); // "false"
console.log(1 in a); // "false"
console.log(2 in a); // "true"
```

Standard arrays in JavaScript are just objects with special behavior assigned to `length`, special behavior assigned to a class of property names (loosely, numeric ones), and that are backed by `Array.prototype`.

This is all in contrast to the newer "typed" arrays, `Int32Array` and such, which are true arrays in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(…
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xXG5p/

You have to make the array dense first. `new Array(n)` creates a sparse array. Sparse arrays do have a `length` but they have **no elements**. Hence, a `.map()` call will not iterate at all.

Using my code above, you will create a dense array that does contain elements (whose values are initially set to `null`).

Comment: Everyone else talks about *why* it cannot work. You provide a solution instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the Mozilla Developer Network says about [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

When you call `new Array(10)`, the `Array` you create believes it is 10-element long but none of its indexes have ever been assigned to. Here's an example of what happens if you use a literal array for which you have not set values for some indices:

```
[1, , 3].map(function () {return "a"})
```

The value you get is:

```
[ 'a', , 'a' ]
```

Because at index 1, no value was assigned.